# Java static list implementation in class

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class Shop
{
    private static List<Product> products = new List<Product>(){};
}
```

code is throwing exception:is not abstract and does not override abstract method subList(int,int) in List

Comment: List is interface you can change it to new ArrayList<Product>()

Comment: 1. Its not throwing an Exception it is giving you a compilation error. 2. What about that error do you not understand? You can't instanciate abstract class or interfaces. You can however crate an anonymous subclass **if** you implement all abstract methods.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @LukasNaruševičius  List is an interface and interface is abstract signatures of the necessary methods needed to be implemented for a class implementing the interface. Interface do not have the implementation, its simply abstraction. Refer my answer, Hope it will be helpful.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43476075/504133

Answer (score 2):

You can't instantiate a List, its just an interface. So instantiate an implementation of it e.g. an ArrayList :

```
public class Shop
{
    private static List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers here `java.lang.List` is an `interface`. I wish to add just a little more to those. `List` being an `interface`  means it defines the necessary **contract** which must be respected and fulfilled by any class to *qualify* as a List. Users of such a class can be sure of the contract being followed so without being worried for the internal source code, they can be sure that it follows all the standard predefined rules for being a list.

`Interface` being just the contract needs to be *implemented* by some *class* for *realization*. An `interface` itself can not be instantiated, its only the `Abstraction` you can not have the object of `interface` without implementing it in a concrete class.

In java you can either use the keyword `implements` with a class and then *must* give implementation for the methods defined by the `interface`. You can also use *annoyonmous class* style. But if any class (including such an annoyonmous class also) implementing an interface, you must provide *concrete* implementation of all the methods defined in the interface. For this you can use

```
public interface AnyInterface{
    void anyMethodA(); // methods are public and abstract by default
    void anyMethodB(); // see as the methods just have signature here, no body
}
```

Now you can use annoyonmous style as below using **curly braces.**

```
AnyInterface objectOfAnnoyomousClass = new AnyInterface(){
     public void anyMethodA(){
          // curly braces implies a method body, here you can have the method implemented 
     }
     public void anyMethodB(){

     }
 };
```

`java.util` classes have the implemetation of `java.util.List` such as `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`.

```
private static List<Product> products = new LinkedList<Product>();
```

There is plenty of material available for java collections including the very well java docs.

**P.S. `static` has actually nothing to do with the compile time issue you are having in the code you showed.

Answer (score 0):

`List` is an interface. You can't initialize an instance of an interface. You need to instead initialize a class that implements `List` like `ArrayList`.

```
private static List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>(){};
```